# How to implement automation testing for mobile push notifications?

Tags: mobile

Scenario:The mobile push notifications will be triggered in server.
The same alerts should be validated in the application in device / emulators. How to implement automation testing for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can't using the tools provided by Apple or Google for notifications. I would suggest that you mock this part.setup a dedicated tool using